# How to know which imageview is selected

Tags: android, android-intent, android-imageview

I have three ImageViews which I created by using a loop. I've already defined the variable pictureSelected in the Activity to track which ImageView is clicked. Strangely in onActivityResult, this pictureSelected variable value is reset to 0, regardless which ImageView I click. Next, I store the pictureSelected to an Intent extra but the result is the same.

Here is my code:
(this is from function initView called in onCreate)

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        ImageView temp = new ImageView(this);
        String url = "/images/"+user.getEmail()+"_"+i+".jpg";
        new ImageLoadTask(this,Constants.SERVER_URL+url,temp).execute();
        int width = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 100, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        int height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 100, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        temp.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(width, height));
        final int finalI = i;
        temp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pictureSelected = finalI;
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("selected",pictureSelected);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                Log.d("pict select",Integer.toString(pictureSelected));
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 1);

            }
        });
        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutProfilePictures);
        linearLayout.addView(temp);
        profilePictures.add(temp);
    }
```

**onActivityResult**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
    Log.d("selected from result",Integer.toString(imageReturnedIntent.getIntExtra("selected",0)));
    switch(requestCode) {
        case REQ_CODE_PICK_IMAGE:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                        selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();

                Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
                profilePictures.get(pictureSelected).setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
                user.getPhotoUri()[pictureSelected]=filePath;

                Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object
                byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
                String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
                String url = user.getEmail() + "_"+pictureSelected+".jpg";
                InstagratApplication.getSocket().emit("upload image",url, encodedImage);
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this via setTag()

Here is example:

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
            ImageView temp = new ImageView(this);
            String url = "/images/"+user.getEmail()+"_"+i+".jpg";
            new ImageLoadTask(this,Constants.SERVER_URL+url,temp).execute();
            int width = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 100, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            int height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 100, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            temp.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(width, height));
            temp.setTag(url);
            temp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String selectedPictureUrl = v.getTag();
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.putExtra("selected",selectedPictureUrl);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 1);

                }
            });
            LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutProfilePictures);
            linearLayout.addView(temp);
            profilePictures.add(temp);
        }
```

Comment: And how do I retrieve the intent onActivity result?

Answer (score 0):

Does the Log.d also print out 0?

In the example code here, you never actually set the pictureSelected variable in the onActivityResult method. If it's the same in your code, that would explain your problem.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), finalI);
```

and in onACtivityResult

```
if(requestCode==0)
{
    //for first imageview
}
else if(requestCode==1)
{
    //for second imageview
}
else if(requestCode==2)
{
    //for third imageview
}
```

Comment: Using the requestCode is a good idea, but doing an if-then-else is not (he could just use requestCode the same way they are already using pictureSelected).